# What can local governments do to reform the police & policing?

Tags: united-states, policy, police, local-government

Much of the oversight power for police departments and sheriff departments is with local government.

For example, in Michigan, the elected officials that oversee police departments in cities are *City Councils* (in weak Mayor systems) and *Mayors* (in strong Mayor systems). In counties, the elected officials that oversee sheriff departments are the *County Sheriff* and *County Commission*.

**Example Policies**

- [Implement body worn cameras](https://www.policeforum.org/assets/BWCCostBenefit.pdf)
- [Ban chokeholds](https://nyassembly.gov/Press/files/20200608a.php) (passed statewide, but could be adopted at the local level)
- Decriminalize ordinances (reduce certain offenses from misdemeanors to civil infractions)

**Example Websites dedicated to police reform**

- [Seven Last Words](https://sevenlastwords.org/)
- [ACLU: Reforming Police](https://www.aclu.org/issues/criminal-law-reform/reforming-police)

What policies or ordinances can be enacted by these bodies that would work toward better policing? Are there organizations that have local government specific policy suggestions?

Comment: Please define better for the purposes of this question.

Comment: @Azor - I've made the question more specific.

Comment: Things that come to my layman mind include: police/citizen review boards, opening up police records like they do criminal records, eliminating bail for petty offenses, running a police complaint hotline, publishing arrest and pullover stats, expanding "shadow a cop" programs, gathering testimonials from folks helped by police, requiring cops to live in-jurisdiction, banning tasers in non-life-threatening situations, mandating cross-training with EMT and FD, holding fun events near/by police stations, and holding public Q+A sessions with chiefs and sheriffs at normally-scheduled meetings.

Comment: Almost everything? It seems to me this is a self-answered question considering the examples given... (Maybe you'd like to focus just on your last sub-question? " Are there organizations that have local government specific policy suggestions?")

Comment: It is a substantive question, because it asks if reforms work or not.

Comment: I asked this question because there is a [question about what can be done at the federal level](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/56747/what-could-the-us-federal-government-do-to-reform-the-police), but there was no local level question.